# Trying to figure out if my processor supported RAM I just brought

Tags: memory, cpu

I just brought G. Skill RipJaws and this is my first time buying RAM to update my computer.

When it arrived today it said on the package it was compatible with Intel Core i7, Core i5, Core i3 and AMD AM3+ / APU platforms.

My processor is AMD FX(tm) - 6120 Six-Core Processor, so I wanted to check in with people here to see if the RAM I had was compatible.  The way I was reading it I thought it mean AMD AM3+ (meaning the + was above that version as well)

If my RAM for my processor isn't supported what is the worst thing that would happen?

Also it sounds like my computer is making more of a humming noise since I changed the RAM as well....

Comment: AM3+ is a socket type.  The FX 6120 is a AM3+ socketed processor.  What exactly is your question?  If the system turned on, and booted, then the memory is obviously compatible. AM3 and AM3+ are backwards compatible with one another.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your motherboard or the type of RAM you bought. In general, what you have to watch out for is whether you bought the correct type of memory. For example, if you buy DDR4 memory but your CPU and motherboard only supports DDR3, it literally won't fit.

Now, assuming you have the right type of memory, you also need to be a little concerned about the voltage and the speed. The AMD FX 6120 CPU supports DDR3-1866. You can probably use slower memory (e.g. DDR3-1600). You could run faster memory at a slower speed (e.g. buy DDR-2400 but run it at 1866) almost certainly without issue. You could try overclocking and running it at full speed, but your system may not be stable if you do so. All of these settings are typically available in your BIOS, though many modern systems will just pull the appropriate settings automatically.

You can most likely ignore everything so far, given that it sounds like the memory fits and your computer boots up and recognises the RAM. I'd strongly recommend you use [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/) to run a thorough test of your RAM. That will validate the RAM itself and also make sure it is working properly in your system.

I can think of no reasonable explanation why your computer would be humming after you have installed more memory. Most likely, you are imagining it. It's possible, I suppose, that your extra RAM is putting out enough extra heat for some fans to be running a little faster, but that's probably a bit of a stretch. There's nothing on the RAM chips themselves that would generate an audible hum.